# Bootstrap 3 Dashed Progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am struggling with styling my progress bar in Bootstrap 3. What I am trying to make is this: [image]

I've been doing some stuff with adding progress-bar-striped and changing the background-image without any succes.

Tried to a working snipped but does not seems to work.

Any ideas on how to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If you increase `width`, progress bar will increase also.

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
  <div class="progress-stripes"></div>
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-stripes {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 9%,
              white 9%,
              white 10.1%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

or

You can also modify the example from the documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress-stacked) and add class `active`

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar active"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar stripe"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
      border-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
      box-shadow: none;
      background-color: silver;
      width: 9%;
}

.active {
      background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);
}

.stripe {
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 1.1%;
}
```